# Why does list.append(temporary variable) in for loop return infinite loop?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Newbie here. Can you **please** explain why the following lines of code return an infinite loop?

**First:**

```
list = [1,2,3]
for i in list:
   list.append(1)
```

Why does it return an infinite loop and does not add 3 "1" elements to the list?

**Second:**

```
list = [1,2,3]
for i in list:
   list.append(i)
```

Same here, returns an infinite loop of the list [1,2,3].

**Third:**
Why does the following snippet of code not return anything(even an infinite loop) to the terminal?

```
list = [1,2,3]
for i in list:
   list.append(1)

print(list)
```

Can you please explain the logic or the order behind the loop?

Comment: Suggest to learn how to debug small program/code in this great visual platform - https://pythontutor.com/

Comment: Note - that `list` is Python built-in, so try to avoid using it as the variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinite loop is created because you are appending a value to your list WHILE (not after) you're iterating over it.

You're saying for every element in your list (3 total), append one element of value 1 (thus adding 3 more), but you're still in the `for i in list` part, so you would then have to append one element of value 1 to every element in your list (now 6), and so on.

Same thing for your second example, except the value is i instead of 1.

Third snippet is never reaching the `print(list)` as you're in an infinite loop above, until that loop is over (which would be never) the following code would not run.

Answer (score 0):

But then, why when iterating over a string, and doing kinda the same thing, it isn't an infinite loop?

```
string = 'a'
for i in string:
    string += 'a'
print(string)
```

It still prints out string variable ('aa')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).